# Windows laptop not connecting to internet over router WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, laptop

I have tried connecting my Windows 10 home (1909) laptop with my router's WiFi, it gets connected but shows "no internet".

The router's "WiFi internet" is working fine, because I have connected my phone to it without any problems.

I thought that it might be a issue of the wireless adapter of my laptop, but that is working when I connect it to a hotspot over my phone. It's also working in the case of USB tethered connection.
What shall I do?

[EDIT: THE PROBLEM HAS BEEN RESOLVED]

Comment: What OS are you using? Is the laptop able to at least find the WiFi? Do you have MAC filtering enabled on your router?

Comment: - Windows 10 home edition(Done the feature update 1909 today)
- Yes, laptop is able to detect the wifi along with ever possible connections, but when I connect to the router wifi it shows,"connected,no internet".
- Actually it's the apartment wifi,so I can't tell you. Is there any way to find out?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main directions to follow:

1. The laptop never managed to connect to any WiFi network.
   In that case the problem involves the WiFi adapter itself and may be:

   - Verify if the manufacturer's website has a more recent driver,
   - There's a lesser chance for a hardware problem, but try using an external
     USB WiFi adapter to check.
2. The laptop works fine somewhere else.
   In this case you may try the following.

   - Check laptop and router for outdated wireless modes.
     These modes have names like 802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11n, and 802.11ac, where
     802.11b is the oldest and the slowest while 802.11ac is the latest and fastest.
     Your adapter and the router may not use the same modes.
     From the fact that your phone works, I would guess that the problem is with your
     adapter.
   - Run Windows *Troubleshooting > Network and Internet*
   - Run the command `ipconfig /flushdns` to flush the DNS cache.
   - Use a fixed DNS server.
     Run *Settings > Network & Internet > Change adapter options*,
     double-click the adapter, double-click "Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)",
     check "Use the following DNS-Server addresses", enter
     the DNS-Servers: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`, finally click OK.
     While you are there, check that "Obtain an IP address automatically" is checked.
   - Reset TCP/IP.
     Run a Command Prompt (cmd) as Admin and enter the command
     `netsh int ip reset resettcpip.txt`.
   - Disable Fast Startup.
     Run *Power Options > Choose what the power buttons do >
     Change settings that are currently unavailable*,
     uncheck "Turn on fast startup (Recommended)", click *Save changes* and
     reboot the computer.
   - Disable temporarily antivirus software.

You will find some more possible fixes in the article
[10 Step by Step Fix to WiFi Connected But No Internet Access](https://techwiser.com/wifi-connected-but-no-internet-access/).